# Checking WMAppPRHeader.xml in XNA with Windows Phone 7

Tags: c#, xna, windows-phone, xna-4.0

I'm developing a game for Windows Phone 7.1 with XNA framework.
I know there is a way to prevent piracy for Windows Phone 7 (and 8.0, 8.1) - checking if the file "WMAppPRHeader.xml" exists in app directory.
I'm using this code:

```
try
{
  Stream stream = TitleContainer.OpenStream("WPAppPRHeader.xml");
  if (stream.CanRead)
  {
    stream.ReadByte();
    stream.Close();
  }
}
catch
{
  //file read error, it means it was hacked
}
```

When use this code and upload my game to Windows phone marketplace as a "**Beta**" app, it **works great**. File "WPAppPRHeader.xml" is readable from my game and the test is passed.
But, when upload **the same XAP** in Windows Phone marketplace as a **public app**, this **code fails** and my game thinks that it was hacked (I'm checking this somewhere in the middle, so microsoft testers doesn't event recognise that something is wrong and my game succesfuly passes certification).

So, what am I doing wrong? Why the same code, the same XAP is working when it's Beta, and not working when it's Public?

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know why TitleContainer.OpenStream is working in beta and not working in public market, but here is the code, that works in public market:
System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load("WPAppPRHeader.xml");